# What is the minimum timeout of the balloon message?

Tags: wpf, notifyicon

I'm using Notification Icon to get my application to show message from the system tray: a pop-up/balloon message(s) are showed when I called

I tried to set it to 100 miliseconds but it doesn't work - the notification is showed longer than what I have set it to be. Please help!

Comment: There might be a better error description than *"it doesn't work"*...

Comment: What do you mean by a balloon message?  A tooltip or a some thing custom?  I found lots of examples when I searched for balloon message.  Please provide some additional information.

Comment: @gehho: There's no error indeed.

Comment: @Zamboni: I update my question to provide more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is different for different versions of windows.  Unfortunately, like just about everything else with balloon messages, your settings are merely hints and windows will do whatever it feels it should.